# Можно ли возобновить работу Scanner после его закрытия? Если можно то как?

Tags: java, eclipse, scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;


            // Изначальный счёт в "банке"
            int BankAccount = 0;

            // Сумма пополнения
            int Deposit = 0;


            out.println("Ваш баланс: " + BankAccount);

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Переменная для получения согласия (y/n) на проведение "транзакции"
            char retry;

            // Предлагаю пополнить счёт и возобновляю работы цыкла если char retry != y && n
            do {

                out.print("Не хотите пополнить счёт? (y/n)");

                // "Указываю на чтения переменной пользователем типа char"
                retry = keyboard.findWithinHorizon("." , 0).charAt(0);

            } while (retry != 'y' && retry != 'n');

            // При получении доступа (Мы ввели y)
            if (retry == 'y') {
                out.println("Укажите сумму пополнения: ");

            // Указываем сумму пополнения
            Deposit = keyboard.nextInt();

                if (Deposit < 10000) {
                    BankAccount = BankAccount + Deposit;
                    keyboard.close();
                }

                // Если Deposit > 10000 отказываем т.к сумма "очень большая"
                if (Deposit > 10000 ) {
                    out.println("Простите, но: " + Deposit + " слишком большая сумма.");

                    // Просим указать сумму еще раз (...<= 10000)
                    out.println("Укажите сумму до 10тыс.");

                    // Возобновить работу Scanner keyboard тут
                    if (Deposit < 10000) {
                        BankAccount = BankAccount + Deposit;
                        keyboard.close();
                    }
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

На момент комментария "// Возобновить работу Scanner keyboard тут" сканер не закрыт. Никто не мешает использовать `Deposit = keyboard.nextInt();` в этом месте.
С другой стороны, имена переменных должны начинаться с маленькой буквы. Также что будет, если ввести сумму 10000? Стоило бы вместо написания нового условия написать else к первому

```
if (deposit <= 10000) {
      bankAccount = bankAccount + deposit;
      keyboard.close();
} else {
      // Если Deposit > 10000 отказываем т.к сумма "очень большая"
     out.println("Простите, но: " + deposit + " слишком большая сумма.");
     // Просим указать сумму еще раз (...<= 10000)
     out.println("Укажите сумму до 10тыс.");

     // Возобновить работу Scanner keyboard тут
     deposit = keyboard.nextInt();
     if (deposit < 10000) {
        bankAccount = bankAccount + deposit;
        keyboard.close();
     }
}`
```

Если отвечать на вопрос прямо: нет, сканер нельзя открыть после закрытия. Можно только создать новый.